# A simple proof about $e^x$?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, derivatives

Do you guys think this is correct? I am trying to prove that there is no single-term polynomial function (oxymoron, I know) $f(x)$ which is always (or at least as x approaches infinity) greater than $e^x$ (I will try to expand this to any polynomial function later). Let $f(x)$ be such a function with the lowest possible degree. Then that means that the slope of $f$ will have to be greater than the slope of $e^x$ as x approaches infinity. This means that $f'(x)>e^x$ as x approaches infinity. However, we already assumed that $f(x)$ is the lowest degree which is greater than $e^x$, but $f'(x)$ is one degree lower than $f$. Therefore, this is a contradiction. What do you guys think? Is this valid? Thanks!

Comment: No, you are wrong. For example, the function $-\frac 1 x$ is increasing and has the slope > $0$, but $-\frac 1 x < 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: He was right when he stated a necessary condition for $f(x)>e^x$ for $x$ sufficiently large is that $f'(x)>e^x$ for $x$ sufficiently large.

Comment: I gave you the contradiction with it

Comment: @Harold: $-\frac 1x$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: @amWhy so what? This method is anyway intuitive. The proof of correctness of this method is equivalent to solving the original problem, it makes no sense. And it isn't correct in the common case even for the simple functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this proof a lot. I think we can try to tighten it up a bit, though.

The main thing I would like you to justify is that "the slope of $f$ will have to be greater than the slope of $e^x$ as $x$ approaches infinity." In other words, there exists some $N\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x) \geq e^x$ for all $x\geq N$. Can you prove this?

Hint: Try supposing $f(x)\geq e^x$ for $x\geq M$, but $e^x \geq f'(x)$ for all $x\geq N$ and get a contradiction through integration.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later.

Answer (score 6):

For **any** polynomial $p(x)$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{p(x)}{e^x}=0$. This can be shown, for example, by using L'Hospital's Rule, and in other ways.

Your argument uses the derivative in a different way. The argument is somewhat informal, but it can be made formal. One could use induction. Let us prove by induction on degree that $\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{p(x)}{e^x}=0$.

We need to prove the degree $1$ base case. For the induction step, suppose the result holds for polynomials of degree $k$. We show it holds for polynomials of degree $k+1$. After a certain point $B$, by the induction hypothesis, we have $|p'(x)|\lt 1$. So $|p(B)+x)|\lt |p(B)|+x$. Thus the ratio $\frac{p(B+x)}{e^{B+x}}$ approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

**Remark:** If we are allowed to use the power series expansion of $e^x$, there is an easy argument. Let $p(x)$ have degree $n$. For positive $x$, the power series expansion of $e^x$ shows us that $e^x\gt \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$. Now we can show easily that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{p(x)}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}=0.$$

Comment: is there some sort of simple proof of this? I thought this was essentially what he was trying to prove (I realize L'Hôpital's rule would work (which is similar to what the OP does))

Comment: Yea I was actually just working with L'Hopital's rule and I was thinking about this.

Comment: @DanZimm: Remember, this is just a fact. No polynomials can beat exponential near infinity.

Comment: @Inceptio that seems to be exactly what the OP is trying to prove, so in this case it doesn't seem to be /fact/